# Rails 5 custom query with multiple keywords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `product` and `tag` model that have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association through a join table `products_tags`. I have many products with the Limestones tag and many with a Mouldings tags, but I am wanting to show only those products that have both.  I know I am missing something that is basic to Rails/Ruby, but I'm still too noob to see it.

The code below I am trying gives me the error `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "tag"`

**products_controller.rb**

```
...
def index
      if params[:query]
        @products = Product.search_for(params[:query]).includes(:tags)
        @mouldings = @products.where('tag.name LIKE ? AND tag.name LIKE ?', 'Mouldings', 'Limestones')
      else
        ...
      end
end
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to the following `tags` instead of `tag`

```
@mouldings = @products.where('tags.name ILIKE ? AND tags.name ILIKE ?', 'Mouldings', 'Limestones')
```

because your table name is `tags` not `tag` and it clearly indicating

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "tag"

**Update**

```
@products = Product.search_for(params[:query]).where('true')
@mouldings = @products.includes(:tags).where('tags.name ILIKE ? AND tags.name ILIKE ?', '%Mouldings%', '%Limestones%')
```

**Update 2**

```
@mouldings = @products.includes(:tags).where('tags.name ILIKE ?', '%Mouldings%')
@limestones = @mouldings.where('tags.name ILIKE ?', '%Limestones%')
```

Comment: now I get `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "tags"
LINE 1: ...search_0a3e27b8ca818264d75c8d.pg_search_id WHERE (tags.name ...`

Comment: @StudioRooster See this update section, updated the answer

Comment: I am getting a blank page with no products now, so I decided to try removing one of the bind variables and just use `'tags.name ILIKE ?', '%Mouldings%'` and it worked, I got all the products tagged `Mouldings`--I tried with `Limestones` too and got all products tagged `Limestones`.  It seems adding multiple bind variables is conflicting with something.

Comment: Yes that is because it is `AND` that means this product and `Mouldings` `AND` `Limestones`